# Отправка документов на почту Python

Tags: html, python, python-3.x, flask

Есть форма с которой я получаю документы(pdf, txt, png и т.д) и отправляю на почту. Все работает хорошо, за исключением одного момента. Я могу выбирать эти документы только из папки где весь код, если выбираю из другой директории то ошибка `No such file or directory`. Как сделать так, чтобы из любой папки можно было выбирать?

`python:`

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET','POST'])
def profile():
   file = request.form['file']
   password = "mypass"
   msg['From'] = "mymail"
   msg['To'] = "anothermail"
   msg['Subject'] = "Subject"
   msg = MIMEMultipart()
    
   file_to_send = MIMEApplication(open(file, 'rb').read())
   file_to_send.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment', filename=file)
   msg.attach(file_to_send)
    
   server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com: 587')
   server.starttls()
    
   server.login(msg['From'], password)
   server.sendmail(msg['From'], msg['To'], msg.as_string())
return render_template('profile.html', file=file)
```

`profile.html:`

```
<input type='file' class="form-control" name="file" id="uploadPDF">
<button class="btn btn-primary send">
  Send
</button>
```